# Missing script: "serve" error when trying to serve my vue project

Tags: typescript, vue.js

How can I resolve this error?

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "serve"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DARINC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-13T05_40_44_233Z-debug-0.log
```

I ran

```
npm install
npm git
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: Check your *package.json*, it should have *"scripts"* like ```"serve": "vue-cli-service serve",```

Comment: Hi ! I updated your title with the error text so people can more easily find your question. Also formatted shell input / output in your question. The message text asks you to use `npm run` to see a list of scripts. What's the output of that?

Answer (score 1):

To run the "npm run serve" script you should:

1. Be in the directory where the package.json file is located.
2. In the "scripts" section of the package.json file, you must have the serve command.
   https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/scripts

Example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "set MODE_BUILD=development&&webpack serve --mode development",
  },
```

According to your *Missing script error: "serve"* in the package.json file, you don't have such command.

Maybe your project can start by another command named *start/dev/start:dev etc.*

If you can't solve the problem, attach the "scripts" section of package.json as well.